# Dedicated application pool to WCF service or the website on a low RAM server?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7, application-pool

I have a single core server with 1 GB RAM. I have a website on one domain and a WCF service on its sub-domain. Both of these websites have dedicated IIS application pool allotted. But to minimize memory consumption, I want to disable any one's dedicated pool option. But I am in confusion of which will take more RAM. What my thinking is I should disable main website's pool and let WCF service use a dedicated pool alone. What do you prefer?